# Declare class member to have internal linkage

Tags: c++

Basically I have code which looks like this inside a header file:

```
class Bar;
class Foo
{
public:
   Bar GetBar();
};

class Bar
{
    Foo CreateFoo() {}
};

Bar Foo::GetBar()
{...}
```

The problem with this code is that as soon as the header is included in more then one file the linker will complain that there are multiple definitions of `Foo::GetBar`. However I can't put it inside the class definition where that would work, because Bar isn't defined at that point. I don't want to put it inside a seperate .cpp file, because the rest of the library I'm writing (which isn't that heavy weight anyway) is mostly templates I would have to place in a header anyway and it seems a bit anoying to require linking something else in only because I had to put one function outside the header.

So is there anyway to solve this problem without creating another .cpp file?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
inline Bar Foo::GetBar()
{...}
```

Comment: One question though, since `inline` is basically a hint to the compiler, but does not actually force the compiler to inline the function, does this still works if the compiler decides not to inline it ?

Comment: @Matthieu: it also gives the function "inline linkage", which basically means you're allowed multiple definitions (as long as they're all the same).

Answer (score 0):

You can declare this `Foo::GetBar()` function inline. I should solve the multiple definitions.

Answer (score 0):

Make the function explicitly inline:

```
inline Bar Foo::GetBar()
{...}
```